# work with TJ operator

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, itext

i work with iText librarie in order to create and then manipulate PDF documents.
let us we have a document which contains a simple string such as "Hello world".
So in the pdf file structure, we must have (Hello world)Tj.
The problem is how can i set position for each character by **using java code** (we can also talk about the TJ operator).
I promise that the person that he/her helps me and gives me ideas, i will put his/her name as reference in my project :)

any answer apreciated :)

Best regards,

Comment: *The problem is how can i set position for each character* - what exactly are your requirements? After all, if you merely want to position each character individually, you can simply use a Tj for each individual chartacter after setting the text matrix before. Or are you asking how to exactly do that in iTextSharp and C# or iText and Java?

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is how can i set position for each character by using java code

Using iText you can easily position any Text fragments (including single characters) by using the text positioning and showing methods of `PdfContentByte.` If you want to wrap that functionality, you can use a helper class like this:

```
public class ContentWriter
{
    public ContentWriter(PdfContentByte content) throws DocumentException, IOException
    {
        this.content = content;
        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont();
        content.beginText();
        content.setFontAndSize(bf, 12);
    }

    // x and y are offsets relative to the start coordinates of the most recent write call
    public ContentWriter write(float x, float y, String text)
    {
        if (finished)
            throw new IllegalStateException("ContentWritr session already finished.");
        content.moveText(x, y);
        content.showText(text);
        return this;
    }

    public void finish()
    {
        if (!finished)
        {
            content.endText();
            finished = true;
        }
    }

    final PdfContentByte content;
    boolean finished = false;
}
```

It can be used like this:

```
public void testShowSomePositionedContent() throws DocumentException, IOException
{
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("positionedContent.pdf"));
    document.open();
    PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
    new ContentWriter(cb).
        write(100, 400, "A").
        write(20, 0, "B").
        write(18, 2, "C").
        write(10, 7, "D").
        finish();
    document.close();
}
```

This sample code creates this:

[image: letters A, B, C, and D positioned as per the sample code]

As you also also talked about PDF operators, you might be interested in how that looks like in the PDF itself:

```
BT
/F1 12 Tf
100 400 Td
(A)Tj
20 0 Td
(B)Tj
18 2 Td
(C)Tj
10 7 Td
(D)Tj
ET
```

As the `ContentWriter` helper class only requires a `PdfContentByte` instance, it can also be used with the UnderContent or OverContent of some page in a `PdfStamper.`

Comment: when you get the solution of our problem, please tell me and post me the code PLEASE.

Comment: As mentioned before: Unless someone else already has done that and is prepared to share the code, I consider that a task taking **at least** some weeks of continuous work, more likely some months, especially as your task is not yet very well defined: You want to take a generic PDF and re-position characters in it. But how exactly do you want to re-position? Just change the character spacing? Or do other manipulations, too? And the character spacing of which glyph sequences? All of them? Glyph sequences at some position? Sequences representing a given string? Clarify your requirements!

Comment: i want to do the "re-position" manipulation task and change the character spacing

Comment: And the character spacing of which glyph sequences? All of them? Glyph sequences at some position? Sequences representing a given string?

Comment: yes all of them. I just want the principle in order to know how ti edit a pdf :(

Comment: That looks like chapter 15 of [iText in Action — 2nd Edition](http://itextpdf.com/book/)... and I doubt that the author approved that the chapter is published on what-when-how.com. Essentially you'll find some information on using the parser package I mentioned earlier.

Comment: *all of them. I just want the principle in order to know how to edit a pdf* --- hhmmmm, possibly feasible.

Comment: i read the chapter 15 in Itext in Action but i still don't know how to replace a text to another :(

Comment: i think that i want to use PdfBox, about this tool, i am sure that i can replace any string in the document. Please get me your name to put you as reference

Comment: In this respect PDFBox has the advantage that it has a public API for content manipulation while itext offers the building blocks and contains an example, the OCGRemover, but not a finished public API. The **real** difficulty of content manipulation tasks is beyond that, though, because PDF is complex.

Comment: true, pdf is very complex.. Alas

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void CreatePdf(String src){
    Rectangle rec= new Rectangle(400,400);
    Document doc= new Document(rec);
    PdfWriter writer= PdfWriter.getInstance(doc,nweFileOutputStream("doc.pdf"));
    PdfContentByte content=writer.getDirectContent();
    doc.open();
    BaseFont bf=BaseFont.createFont();
    String texte="hello";
    content.setCharacterSpacing((float)2.5);
    content.setFontAndSize(bf,12);
    content.beginText();
    content.showText(texte);
    content.endText();
    document.close();
    }
    public static void ManipulatePdf(String src, String dest){
    PdfReader read= new PdfReader("doc.pdf");
    PdfStamper stamper= new PdfStamper(read,new FileOutPutStream("doc_modifie.pdf"));
    PdfContentByte canvas= stamper.getUnderContent(1);
    canvas.setFontAndSize(bf,12);
    canvas.setCharacterSpacing((float)6);
    canvas.beginText();
    canvas.showText(texte);
    canvas.endText();
    stamper.close();

    //now how to modify the character spacing to 6 for example and then replace the modified //string instead of the old string in the document
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

public void ManipulatePdf(String src, String dest){
PdfReader read= new PdfReader("document.pdf");
        PdfStamper stamper= new PdfStamper(read, new FileOutputStream("document_modifié.pdf"));

```
    PdfContentByte content= stamper.getUnderContent(1);

    LocationTextExtractionStrategy lteStrategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
    String texte= PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(read, 1, lteStrategy);
    pdflayer= new PdfLayer("Overrite", stamper.getWriter());
    content.setColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);
    content.beginLayer(pdflayer);
    content.fill();
    PdfGState pgState = new PdfGState();
    content.setGState(pgState);
    content.setColorFill(BaseColor.WHITE);
    content.setCharacterSpacing((float)6);
    content.beginText();
    content.setTextMatrix(15, 385);
    content.showText("hello");
    content.endText();
    content.endLayer();
    stamper.close();
     read.close();
```

}